# Alert Volume won't unmute

Tags: sound, ubuntu-mate

[image]

So I have an issue where the Alert volume keeps going to 0 whenever I reboot. I prefer to have the sounds on, but they won't stay on when I leave Ubuntu (this happens on all Desktop Environments). Is there a way to force this to stay at full volume every time? The normal sound isn't effected, it's just the Alert sounds.

Comment: other than mute button, I've never known that thing to control the alert volume... The alert volume will be at the volume of the main volume. Mine returns/stays at the left, but the alert sound is always present. The only time there is no sound is when the mute box is checked.... unchecking mute and adjusting the slider to any point returns it to full volume (the volume of the main output volume)... I believe this has been a bug for a while.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.10